# How to make a windows forms application in C# that can receive data from a serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have this (Working) code for receiving data from serial ports and displaying it in a console application in c#.

```
#region Namespace Inclusions
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

namespace SerialPortExample
{
  class SerialPortProgram
  {
    // Create the serial port with basic settings
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1",
      9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
      // Instatiate this class
      new SerialPortProgram();
    }

    private SerialPortProgram()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");

      // Attach a method to be called when there
      // is data waiting in the port's buffer
      port.DataReceived += new 
        SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

      // Begin communications
      port.Open();

      // Enter an application loop to keep this thread alive
      Application.Run();
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
      SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
  // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
  Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
    }
  }
}
```

But how would I transfer this code into working on a Windows Forms Application?

I know this is a vague question, but please if possible could you provide some example code for such an application.

Comment: Instead of consol.writeline append the output in a multiline textbox.

Comment: It is already more or less WinForm app as it is using `Application.Run`. Just add some form with multiline textbox for output and you are done...

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to c#, how would I do that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the following lines to replace your Application.Run statement you should be ready to go.
(remove your original port.DataReceived line)

```
var frm = new Form { Height = 200, Width = 200 };
var txt = new TextBox {Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Multiline=true };
frm.Controls.Add(txt);
port.DataReceived += (sender, args) => { 
        if (txt.InvokeRequired)
        {
            txt.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { 
                txt.Text += port.ReadExisting(); 
                }));
        } 
        else  
        {
           txt.Text += port.ReadExisting(); 
        }
   };
Application.Run( frm);
```